# Filtering input with iptables: -i <interface> versus -d <ip>

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

I'm changing my iptables setup to cope with the addition of a new uplink, which now receives its configuration through DHCP. I currently list my interface's IP addresses directly in my rules, which are kept in a file in /etc and restored by iptables-restore. For instance a rule like the below allows access to my web server:

```
* filter
# ...
-A INPUT -i ethX -d XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80
```

I'm wondering whether I could just drop the -d XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX section without creating any significant additional risk, changing the above to simply:

```
-A INPUT -i ethX -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80
```

This would avoid the need to update my rules file when the DHCP-provided addresses change. It appears as if it is in practice equivalent, since I believe the only packets arriving on that interface with that destination port defined would be packets I would be receiving directly anyway. But since this interface is connected to a rather noisy cable-connected provider, I wonder about packets arriving that are actually set to some other destination address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest refactoring your rules to use interface identifiers instead of individual IPs. It's much easier to manage that way.

Assigning multiple IPs to a given network interface is becoming more common, and could be quite common indeed with increasing implementation of IPv6 in environments with multiple ISP uplinks.

While yours appears that it may be operating as a router, under proper IPv6 implementations there is no NAT. This would require IP assignments on all connected interfaces for each of your uplink networks.

No time like the present to get ready for it.

Comment: Thanks -- but I'm not sure whether you are agreeing to my suggestion above (just dropping the IP address) or whether using "interface identifiers" means more than just that. Indeed, this is a router, and I have multiple uplinks which is part of the challenge in maintaining a simple iptables setup.